# Is there a way to check for any state changes made by a user in React?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm working on a modal component where users can edit the contents of a post they created.

[image]

I have it set up where a notification window pops up if the user tries to close the modal without saving.

[image]

However, sometimes users don't make any changes and I don't want them to see this notification, I just want the modal to close.

I could create separate states to store the original state then compare those states to the current states, but I have a lot of states (15) and that seems messy.

I'm wondering if there is a way for me to check if any set of particular states have been changed at all? That way, I would know to show the notification or not.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking--if you need to monitor a change in state then that's what you need to do, noting that there are many libraries that'll do a deep object compare to determine if there have been any changes.

Comment: I want to check if there have been any changes to state on 15 specific states in my component. I'd rather not do that 1 by 1, which seems to be my only option right now.

Comment: Have you tried to stringify your state when your component mounts and whenever you want to check if something has changed, to check the new stringified state with your initial stringified state? So, if something has changed the two strings wont be the same. You can use `const initialState = JSON.stringify(this.state);`

Comment: Also, when you say you have too many states, you mean you have many variables for states and you use useState, or only one object that manages your state inside the component?

Comment: I mean I have 15 variables in state.

Comment: I have most of this working, the problem I'm having now is that the original state is not able to be permanently saved anywhere since I'm using a class. Meaning it's changing the initialState value whenever anything is changed on the page. I've been looking to see if I can save a const outside of render() but havne't had any luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you use hooks, so in your case I would suggest to refactor a little bit your component with the states like below and after this has been done to use the JSON.stringify to check if something has been changed. You will actually have one state as an object.

```
const [var1, setVar1] = useState($initialVar1);
const [var2, setVar2] = useState($initialVar2);
const [var3, setVar3] = useState($initialVar3);

...
const [var14, setVar14] = useState($initialVar14);
```

to

```
const [componentState, setComponentState] = useState({
var1: $initialVar1,
var2: $initialVar2,
var3: $initialVar3
...
})
```

Wherever you want to update the individual states you can use the spread operator

```
setComponentState({
...componentState,
varX: newValue
})
```